# Swapping implementations of an interface

Tags: c++

I've searched around for discussions on this matter, both Google and Stackoverflow; "implementation swapping", "replace implementation" and so on didn't give me any results.

Let's say we have an interface `DB`, and my current implementation is `Postgresql`. Now, I want to swap the implementation out in favor for `MySQL`. What would be an appropriate way to do this? I have a couple of ideas myself:

1. Have `DB.h` and `DB.cpp`, the cpp file containing the Postgresql implementation. Now, just rename `DB.cpp` to `DB.cpp.postgresql` and the MySQL implementation to `DB.cpp`.
2. `Postgresql.h / Postgresql.cpp` and `MySQL.h / MySQL.cpp`, changing the actual `#include<>` statement. This seems wrong; hundreds of files could use this, so that'd result in a lot of seemingly unnecessary work.
3. Implement an IoC Container and resolve the DB driver/connector from there.

Are any of these three the correct, or do we have another kind of common way to achieve this?

Comment: Are you sure, you need only one kind of implementation in your whole Program? If that is the case, then I don't understand, why hundreds of files would include MySQL.h instead of DB.h in the first place.

Comment: 1 and 2 are working on different assumptions, sorry if I didn't make myself clear about that. `DB.h` does not exist in the second example, example 2 is assuming that we don't have `DB.h`, but that the header file for the database connection is named by the actual driver name :-) I'm pretty sure that approach 2) is suboptimal or just plain wrong.

Comment: Btw, this is not an actual case, just a pseudo-example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(warning, uncompiled code ahead)

> DB.h

```
#include <string>
class DB
{
  public:
    virtual bool insert(std::string content) = 0;
    // And whatever other functions your DB interface may need ...
}
```

> MySQL.h

```
#include <DB.h>
class MySQL : public DB
{
  public
    virtual bool insert(std::string content);
}
```

> MySQL.cpp

```
#include <MySQL.h>
bool MySQL::insert(std::string content)
{
  // insert logic here
  return true;
}
```

> same for PostgreSQL.

> createDB.cpp

```
#include <memory>
#include <MySQL.h>
#include <PostgreSQL.h>

enum class DBType { MySQL, PostgreSQL };
std::unique_ptr<DB> createDB(DBType type)
{
  switch(type)
  {
    case DBType::MySQL:
      return std::unique_ptr<DB>{std::make_unique<MySQL(/*constructor arguments here*/)};
    case DBType::PostgreSQL:
      return std::unique_ptr<DB>{std::make_unique<PostgreSQL>(/*constructor arguments here*/)};
  }
}
```

This is also called the Factory Pattern if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: That is indeed a Factory Pattern; don't know why I didn't think of that. Pretty good idea. Thanks. In any case, the MySQL and PostgreSQL would need to have separate header files, that's probably why I didn't think of this kind of abstraction. Makes perfect sense. This, combined with some kind of bootstrapper would make it easy to swap it out so `createDB` is only called in a single place.

Comment: Also note that there is stuff like [ODBC](https://nl.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_DataBase_Connectivity) which should abstract the underlying database details away for you.

Comment: Thanks, I'll look into that. DB was just an example for simplicity, but in the future if I need to connect to a DB, that'll certainly come in handy, so thanks!